# <a href> instead of <input submit> button

Tags: javascript, html

I originally had a submit button.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" class="input" value="Add" name="command" />
```

but now I would like to use a `<a href>` instead.  The issue is, the `value="Add"` is very important.

I'm currently making the `<a href>` like this.

```
<a href="javascript:document.register.submit();">submit</a>
```

Any suggestions?  Issue is, the site is not picking up that this specific `<a href>` was clicked, and therefore won't run my php code.

Comment: what is the actual question, and why do you have two class attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off I highly recommend jquery. It makes a world of difference when working with javascript and simplifies a number of issues especially cross different browsers.

What I suggest is that you create a hidden input to set the value with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFormWithValue(val){
  document.getElementById('command').value = val;
  document.forms["test"].submit();
}
</script>

<form id="test" name="test" action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="" />
</form>

<a href="javascript:submitFormWithValue('foo')">Submit</a>
```

I didn't test my code but it should be close enough to see how it works. Again check out jquery it will make dealing with javascript a lot easier!

Comment: Everyone had great answers, but in the end I did use jQuery.  I've been trying to avoid jQuery thinking it'd be hard to work with.  But once you understand how it works, it does make everything much simpler.

Answer (score 11):

As Pekka suggests: Don't do this. It will make your form unnecessarily be dependent on JavaScript!

The best thing to do is use CSS to style the button to look like a link:

```
input.submit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: +1 this. Not only does the link version depend on JavaScript, it also reacts very poorly when interacted with using other link actions, such as middle-click, drag-and-drop or right-click-bookmark. If it's an action, rather than a link to somewhere, it should be a button. Also, `javascript:` links are concentrated evil and should never be used.

Comment: With styling a button to not look like a button there's one slight limitation: IE will always add a 1px extra padding that you can't remove, and will make the content of the button shift by a pixel when clicked upon. This usually doesn't matter, but if you need the size of the button to be pixel-perfect you have to account for the padding with a browser-specific stylesheet rule.

Comment: Styling the input won't work if you need other elements inside the tag being used as a submit.  An example would be a submit button that had a gradient border, and therefore needs a span tag inside of the submit.

Comment: @OB7 In that case use a `<button type="submit">...</button>`. Also extra elements are often unnecessary, when using newer CSS features such as `:before`/`:after`, etc. Generally JavaScript can often be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Add a hidden field, and an extra line into the javascript:

```
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
<a href="javascript: document.register.command.value='Add'; document.register.submit();">
    Submit
</a>
```

That said, you might be better off using CSS to style the submit button to look how you want it to.