# Convert javascript link to href

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to convert this submit button into a `href` link. The form is not a html form but JavaScript. The button code currently is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Name" onclick="Offer();">
```

How to convert it to a `href` link.

I've tried `onclick="document.Offer();"` but it doesn't work

Comment: What does "convert it to a href link" mean?  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="return theFunction();">Name</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function theFunction () {
        // return true or false, depending on whether you want to allow the `href` property to follow through or not
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could please provide your code so that it might be easier to understand your requirement.

There is a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850358/a-href-instead-of-input-submit-button) post on this check it out.